# Plotting means in R

Tags: r

I want to fit my vectors x ,y to some kind of curve, but they're both about 10k long with x-values very closely packed, so a scatter plot just ends up as a huge mess. What I'd like to do is to plot the AVERAGE of the y-values corresponding to one x-value.

For example:

```
y=rnorm(1000)
x=c(rep(1,500),rep(2,500))
plot(x,y)
```

I'd like this plot to only have two single points, one for x=1 and one for x=2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(unique(x),tapply(y,x,mean))
```

or maybe even

```
plot(tapply(x,x,unique),tapply(y,x,mean))
```